# Set multiple rows of R matrix to same values

Tags: r, matrix

```
m <- matrix(ncol=3,nrow=3)
index <- c(1,3)
row <- c(F,F,T)
m[index,] <- row
```

I want to get the matrix

```
F F T
NA NA NA
F F T
```

But instead, the values are being assigned vertically

```
F T F
NA NA NA
F T F
```

I've tried doing transposes and everything that I can think of, but I can't figure out how to set all the rows equal to the *row* vector without using an ugly for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R follows the [column-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) and so the values in a matrix are filled by column (and not by row as you intended). Try this:

```
m[index,]<-rep(row,each=length(index))
#      [,1]  [,2] [,3]
#[1,] FALSE FALSE TRUE
#[2,]    NA    NA   NA
#[3,] FALSE FALSE TRUE
```